# Tracking filesystem changes in runtime

Tags: security, logging, filesystems

I need to have program that tracks changes made to the file e.g. when I am installing software from supplied installer instead of packages. I do not want to checksum every file in filesystem because It is time consuming and can kill my SSD quickly. I wish application would use kernel abilities (e.g. inotify) to inform application about changes made to filesystem. My scheme would be to launch tracking application then launch program then kill program and save information about changed file to the log file. I wish to track only some directories e.g. I do not care about /tmp or /mnt directory.

Comment: `inotify` won't work very well to track changes for software installs.  `inotify` requires you to watch a specific path - a directory, for example.  You have to get the notification a new directory is created before you can watch for events in that directory.  In the time between the creation of the new directory and when your application adds an inotify event watcher on that directory, files and directories can be created in the new directory *before* your application is watching for them.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So what is the alternative to inotify?